# Does Akamai implement if-modified-since?

Tags: caching, cdn, akamai

I am trying to fine tune one of my applications that uses Akamai for CDN.

I am serving resources that rarely change, but I'd like Akamai to check once in a while just in case.

For this I set the Expires and CacheControl:max-age to 3 days.

My question is: What happens after those 3 days? Does Akamai ask me for the whole content again, or does it ask me if it changed using the if-modified-since header?
If it doesn't, I won't even bother implementing the return of the 304 status code in my application.

Answer (score 1):

The Akamai server will make an IMS request to your origin.

Comment: Any source? I would like more than just your word :)